# Cyclic dependency issue in c# while trying to add references

Tags: c#, cyclic-reference

I have two Class Libraries (Lets say LibA and LibB). LibA is using some fnctions of LibB so I add reference of LibB in LibA.

Now LibB also needs to use some code of LibA. I cant add reference of LibA to LibB now because of cylic dependency thing. What can i do now that my LibB can access code of LibA?

Comment: Put the code into a separate library so that both projects can access it without having a dependency on eachother.

Comment: well any other solution except this inefficent way of copy pasting and code redundancy

Comment: It's not about copy pasting, but _moving_ the code into a separate assembly that all projects get to share.

Comment: So by reducing the dependency and placing the code into another library is inefficient and redundant??

Comment: @user2968369 You don't have to copy-paste the code. You need to move it in another assembly.

Comment: Always amazes me that when the correct solution is posted, the original poster kicks out against it. Why bother asking a question in the first place?

Comment: You might find the SOLID principles worth reading about, they've helped me when laying out projects:
http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/solid-principles-with-real-world-examples/#.Uny2P-LLLNE

Comment: ok guys i get it. you are right about it :).  thanks. another spin-off of this q. If I have a 'window forms application' project and it has a reference to class library lets say LibA. Now LibA wants to access some data of this 'window forms application' project, how to do it now? or the same above mentioned approach will apply here

Comment: Just for completeness sake, you can also merge LibA and LibB into one library. Looks like they are tightly coupled anyway, so maybe they belong together? If they're small, merging them may result in performance benefits as well. Avoid creating too many small assemblies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code should be placed into a new library so that both projects can reuse the code. Further to this, if a new project is added to the solution it also can make use of the shared code.
It's not inefficient or redundant in anyway and is indicative of good design and usability.

Comment: ok you are right about it :). thanks  i get it. another spin-off of this q. If I have a 'window forms application' project and it has a reference to class library lets say LibA. Now LibA wants to access some data of this 'window forms application' project, how to do it now? or the same above mentioned approach will apply here

Comment: In the UI project, pass the data to LibA, such as the Text from a TextBox etc this way LibA does not depend on any WinForm components and can effectively be reused at another point in time.